# Apache ProxyPass with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-proxy, mod-ssl, proxypass

I have a QA setup that consists of multiple internal development servers and one world-accessible provisioning machine that is setup to proxy pass the web traffic.  Everything works fine for non-SSL requests, but I'm having a hard time getting the SSL logic working as well.  Here's a few example vhost blocks.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.168.101:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://192.168.168.111/
    ServerName dev1.site.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.168.101:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.168.111/
    ServerName dev1.site.com
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 192.168.168.101:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://192.168.168.111/
    ServerName dev2.site.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.168.101:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.168.111/
    ServerName dev2.site.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I end up seeing the following error in the provisioner's error log.

```
[Fri Jan 28 12:50:59 2011] [warn] [client 1.2.3.4] proxy: no HTTP 0.9 request (with no host line) on incoming request and preserve host set forcing hostname to be dev1.site.com for uri /
```

As well as the following entry in the destination QA machine's access log.

```
192.168.168.101 - - [22/Feb/2011:08:34:56 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01 / HTTP/1.1" 301 326 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Did you already see [Apache VirtualHost with mod-proxy and SSL](http://serverfault.com/questions/25423/apache-virtualhost-with-mod-proxy-and-ssl)?

Answer (score 1):

Is the virtualHost definition complete? you missed turning on the ssl engine and specifying the key andcert and so on... So I guess there is listenong a plain http receiver at :443 without ssl.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had that specific error message, but I can see a problem in your setup: you have two virtual host listening on 192.168.168.101:443.

You can't do that with SSL, because Apache cannot look at the content of the SSL connection before it is decrypted, so your second SSL virtual host dev2.site.com is ignored.

Comment: That was actually just a transcription error on my part.  The server doesn't actually have multiple SSL hosts on the same IP.